# memory allocation issue - PHP

Tags: php, memory-leaks, memory-management

I am having really weird problem:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 21748 bytes)
```

I understand that error however I am tracking all memory allocation for script and its not getting above: 2883584 in total.

The line before Fatal error is being triggered real memory usage is at a level of 2883584. As described in error above script is trying to allocate just extra 21748 more which is not adding up to 134217728 anyway.

Any ideas why its like that?

P.S.
for memory allocation usage I am using: `memory_get_usage(true)` function.

Comment: Check for any infinite loops.

Comment: also, worth to mention I am running it in cli as a shell script

Comment: no infinite loops, checked that

Comment: Showing some code, or at least naming the function that raises this error would help ;)

Comment: yeah, php is saying that its in imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); however I am doing imagedestroy everytime before creating new and checking memory usage in between and its stays at normal level...

Comment: normal web sizes, I would say max 300kb, and as in error description its trying to allocate just 21748 bytes extra

Comment: since running on cli, any reason not increase to bigger memory?

Comment: yeah, its not a solution, it should fit in 128MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I think I have found out the problem. As it turns out, if there is hard image to process GD2 allocation memory but you can't see it in memory_get_usage and get_peak so quite lame but...

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing `true` to `memory_get_usage`, which will return the true amount of system memory allocated (rather than just `emalloc` usage). The runtime is probably referring to system memory used when terminating your script, which may be much higher (e.g. through extensions which are not `emalloc`ing values).